# Animate two propellers turning in opposite directions

Tags: animation

I'm trying to create an animation for UE5, for a Mk14 WW2 torpedo. That had two propellers, turning in opposite directions (one clockwise, the other counter-clockwise, at the same speed).

The torpedo consists of three meshes, the body, and the two propellers. I have parented the props to the body.

I can do two separate animations, one for each propeller, but it seems a bit inefficient to me.

Is there a way to animate both propellers at the same time, in one animation?

Comment: well...of course you could use drivers (which only makes really sense if you are animating the propellers a lot (so no constant speed, but often changing speed)) but you only have to copy the animation, mirror it and then move it a bit ...i don't know what's inefficient with that.

Comment: @Chris from what I saw, drivers don't export well into UE5? Re inefficiencies - I'd have as many as six torpedoes being animated at once. Having to do 2 tracks per torpedo just for props doesn't seem very efficient to me..

Comment: unfortunately you didn't write that in your original question: that you animated six torpedoes, so i thought you wanted to animated just two propellers. That's why i wrote that comment. I really wish people who ask questions would add all (!) necessary informations in the questions instead then commenting on comments or answers because of "extra wishes" - so please improve your question so that other people won't waste their time. thx.

Comment: Ok, will try to do. TBH, for me, having two tracks when I'd be doing something that is always attached together and never would be split is inefficient regardless of whether I'd animate one object or two, just from quality-of-life perspective (edits, moves etc.). But I understand that's subjective.

Comment: @vlade "quality of life" is a lot exaggerated, isn't it? Here at work when people want to manipulate data, it is the same: when they ask me to write some procedure to do what they want, I ask: how often do you have to do that? 30 times now and then never again? If I try to find a way to do it procedurally and taking all things into account which I have to care for, it takes the same amount of time as doing it 50 to 100 times manually. So that's not really efficient either if it is a one-time action. That's why sometimes it is important to know what you really want to do.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann When I know I'll always use something together, then I'll try to put it together. Not doing so will sooner or later result in a problem in my experience - of coding professionally 30+ years. YMMV, but if I can do it, I prefer to.

Comment: @vlade Sure, but that's what Chris means with maybe wasting others' time. Sometimes you wreck your head to come up with a solution that works in many different scenarios. And someone else says, "if you just need this now quickly, you could simply do it like that" and then it becomes the accepted answer. Sure, the other answer might be helpful for future users, but it is questionable if they come across it and if they pay attention to it when another answer is accepted. And other than coding quick and simple solutions can help, because solutions might change quickly with each Blender version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rig the model with an armature and use the bones to animate it.
Or, since it's a fairly simple animation,you can animate it directly inside UE. You can even make it procedural, making the torpedo an actor and using bluprints to rotate the different parts. But that's outside the scope of this Stack Exchange so I won't dive deeper into it.

Comment: I can do it in a BP no problem (timeline, rotate movement... ). The problem is that I'm doing cinematics, and as far as I can see right now, none of that works in the sequencer - or at least I could not get it going. I'd love a sequencer where I'd have all/most of the logic/animations via BP and then drive the sequence via events/calls to the BP ("flank ahead, rudder 5d left", "open tube 1, fire torpedo at coordinates XYZ"). But that doesn't seem to be possible :(.

Comment: I think it is possible to make blueprint logic run in the sequencer by using an event track in the sequencer.

Comment: you can, but the problem is that the "move" components (timeline, rotate movement etc. ) don't seem to work when you do - or at least I wasn't able to do get them to work.

Comment: interesting. It's been a while since I used Unreal and its sequencer...
If it's not possible, then the next best solution is to rig your torpedo with an armature inside blender, create the rotating proppelers animation in blender and export it as a skeletal mesh, like you would a character or any other rigged mesh.

Comment: Re UE5 - It might be passible, but I could not figure it out, and found many posts from people saying the same. Hence I'm trying Blender first (that seems to be workflow for many people). I think it will end up the way you're describing.